# Not able to click an path element using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, c#, selenium, webdriver

[image]I am working on automating charts data and below is how the data is represented.

`<path id="statdue" opacity="1" fill="#F15A22" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="0" d="M 0 2.3749999999999916 Q… 0 2.3749999999999916 Z" aria-label="Overdue:0">                                                                       <path id="stat7days" opacity="1" fill="#1a1a1a" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="0" stroke-dasharray="0" d="M 0 49.87499999999998 Q …L 0 49.87499999999998 Z" aria-label="7 Days:3" style="visibility: visible;" transform="translate(0,0)">`

I used the code:

`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#statdue")).Click();`

But it was worked for
`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#stat7days")).Click();`

Comment: can you add the full html markup? Not a screenshot as well as what you have tried?

Comment: I provide a screenshot is it oaky?

Comment: provide webdriver code used... check if it is in frame or not

Comment: this is why I was looking for the full code. It could be an iframe or possibly an svg as well.

Comment: I used the code:

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#statdue")).Click();

But it was worked for driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#stat7days")).Click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to need something like this for an xpath.

//*[name()='svg' and @id='statdue']")

Comment: I used this way and worked (//*[name()='svg']//*[@id='statdue']). Thank you

Comment: @RonyBarua If it worked, why didn't you accept the answer?